# PHP - target a multidimensional array element without eval()

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, eval

The goal is to pass a specific array element through custom_format().

**Example:** If $hierarchy = '4:0:2', then $data[4][0][2] = custom_format($data[4][0][2]).

Does anyone know how to replicate the following code **without relying on eval()**?

Current code:

```
$hierarchy = '4:0:2';
$hierarchy = str_replace(':', '][', $hierarchy);
eval("\$data[$hierarchy] = custom_format(\$data[$hierarchy]);");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781524/1396314) to retrieve the value from multidimensional array. It uses dot-separated keys (e.g: `4.0.2`), but you can easily change it to `:`.

Comment: That example will only retrieve a value. I'm trying to actually replace a specific value within a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. It looks like this thread also has some relevant answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851590/array-set-value-using-dot-notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An overly verbose yet elegant option is the following:

```
class MyArray implements ArrayAccess {
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        if(!is_array($offset))
            $offset = explode(':', $value);
        $key = array_shift($offset);
        if($key !== NULL) {
            if($this->$key InstanceOf MyArray) {
                return(isset($this->$key[$offset]));
            }
        }
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        if(!is_array($offset))
            $offset = explode(':', $value);
        $key = array_shift($offset);
        if($key !== NULL) {
            if($this->$key InstanceOf MyArray) {
                return($this->$key[$offset]);
            }
        }
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if(!is_array($offset))
            $offset = explode(':', $value);
        $key = array_shift($offset);
        if($key !== NULL) {
            if(!($this->$key InstanceOf MyArray)) {
                $this->$key = new MyArray;
            }
            $this->$key[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        if(!is_array($offset))
            $offset = explode(':', $value);
        $key = array_shift($offset);
        if($key !== NULL) {
            if($this->$key InstanceOf MyArray) {
                return(unset($this->$key[$offset]));
            }
            if(count($offset) == 0) {
                return(unset($this->$key));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does imply using `MyArray` everywhere you need this kind of array behaviour and perhaps creating a static method that recursively converts arrays and they array children into MyArray objects so that they will respond consistently to this behavior.

One concrete example is the need to change the `offsetGet` method, to check if $value is an `array` then to use the conversion function to convert it to a `MyArray` if you want to access its elements.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<?php
$hierarchy = '4:0:2';
list($a,$b,$c) = explode(':',$hierarchy);
echo $data[$a][$b][$c];
?>
```

Comment: No, sorry I didn't clarify -- assume that $data can have more than 3 dimensions.

Comment: @Jamie actually assume that $data can have any number of dimensions.

Comment: In that case, I can't see any other way than to loop through each of your elements and do an IF on each one until all the keys match up, then do you replace when they all match. Not exactly efficient, but in all honesty, what are you going to do with the array if you don't know how many depths it has?

Comment: We know exactly what depth we need by the $hierarchy string.

Comment: @Matt What Jaimie meant was if we don't know the exact depth at **compile time** as opposed to **run time**.

Comment: Of course I know PHP isn't compiled, but the wording **compile time** takes the meaning of code that is fixed, and analyzable before running it. Eval is an example of constructing code at **run time**. Jaimie said it couldn't be done using only code written by you without using generated code. I disagree as per my example, looping and recursion are two approaches that can solve this issue.