# Best way to transform tag list into structured array from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My database is storing a list like this:

```
ID | name
--- -----
1  | search
2  | search.categories
3  | search.categories.accessories
4  | search.categories.accessories.glasses
5  | search.categories.accessories.hats
6  | filters
7  | filters.payments
8  | filters.payments.creditcard
9  | filters.payments.debitcard
```

Now I want to SELECT it in a recursivelly array just like this:

```
[
    name, childs[
        name, childs[ ... ],
        name, childs[ ... ],
        name, childs[
            name, childs[ ... ],
            name, childs[ ... ],
        ],
    ],
    name, childs[
        name, childs[ ... ],
        name, childs[ ... ],
        name, childs[
            name, childs[ ... ],
            name, childs[ ... ],
        ],
    ]
]
```

What is the best way to achive this? Directly from MySQL or manually string handling?

Comment: You will have to use php to parse the strings and add them to an array. There isn't built in functionality to this either, you will have to make something. There are questions that talk about how to assign a value into an array using "dot notation" like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851590/array-set-value-using-dot-notation) that should help get you started. Also, storing multiple values in a single string field like this is (grandparent.parent.child.etc) usually considered bad practice.

Comment: I wrote an example PHP function to do something similar, but with adjacency-list data instead of path-enumeration data like yours. Anyway, it might serve as an example to get your started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261228/convert-flat-array-to-the-multi-dimensional/3261351#3261351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Laravel you can build a nested array by using `array_set` and using as key the *name* column of your table, taking advantage that you are already storing on dot notation.

Despite you are not exposing what's the purpose of this and why you want to build this structure this way, follows one possible approach.

- Initialize an empty array (`$structure = []`)
- Retrieve all table records an iterate them (use a DB select or model get as you prefer)
- For each table row, perform an `array_set($structure, $listname, $value)`

In your example, I don't see where `$value` could be coming from, but I guess you will grasp the idea.

```
$structure = [];
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    array_set($structure, $row->name, $value);
}
```